# Database Table with pre-defined values

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've created a Table Expenses that has the follows columns:

name : this is the name of the expense, varchar type

value: this is the value of the expense , Double type

date : this is the time to pay the expense. Date type

situation: this is where I got stuck, I need that the user choose between 'Payed','Pendent' and 'overdue'.

How can I create that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use an [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) field. According to the docs:

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

or use an table to store your allowed values ('Payed','Pendent' and 'overdue'), and use a foreign key to that table in your Expenses table.
Basic table creation (I didn't include the foreign key constraint as depending on your table storage engine it may not be supported):

```
CREATE TABLE lst_situations(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Expenses(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    value DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    situation_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: in the second option after create the table lst_situatuions I have to create the insert statement is it?

Comment: That's right, you just INSERT 3 rows, one for each of your allowed values